# Laravel Notification - via specified by user

Tags: laravel, laravel-notification

How can the method `via` in a notification class can be dinamic by the users preferences, one user maybe want to receive via email, the other one, dont

```
public function via($notifiable) {
    return ['database', 'broadcast', 'mail'];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function is receiving the User (`$notifiable`) as a parameter, you could call a method on the `$notifiable` to retrieve the list of channels you want the notification to use.

```
public function via($notifiable) {
    return $notifiable->getNotificationPreferences();
}
```